Cannot execute -h\bin\java to determine the version
Steps to reproduce

set JAVA_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
run PS C:\> flutter doctor --android-licenses
get the error
try to set JAVA_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23
get the same error

Actual results
PS C:\Users\tri36> flutter doctor --android-licenses

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: -h

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(C:\Users\tri36\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/to/windows-android-setup for detailed instructions.

Logs

Logs

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: -h

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(C:\Users\tri36\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/to/windows-android-setup for detailed instructions.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      AndroidLicenseValidator.runLicenseManager (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:410:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:49:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1408:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:420:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:364:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:130:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:93:3)
<asynchronous suspension>


Flutter Doctor output

Doctor output

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at C:\Users\tri36\dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (5 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\tri36\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\tri36\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: -h\bin\java
    ✗ Cannot execute -h\bin\java to determine the version

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.35327.3
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 129.0.6668.101
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 129.0.2792.89

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


solove this problem

Usually development tools don't work wit the latest Java JDK, my advice is only using versions with long-term support of Java like 17 or 21. Anyway your setup is defect as shown by the various messages JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: -h it means the JAVA_HOME variable is set to -h instead of the directory of your JDK.

I run java --version
and the output is
openjdk 21.0.3 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11, mixed mode)


Then set this JDK path as JAVA_HOME env variable and restart your terminal to make sure the updated JAVA_HOME env variable is applied.

Ensure that Java is installed correctly

first you have to check this by running java -version and javac -version in your command prompt.

Make sure JAVA_HOME is set to the correct path of your JDK installation
Here’s how you can set it:

Right-click on This PC or My Computer on your desktop or in File
Explorer and select Properties.
Click on Advanced system settings.
In the System Properties window, click on Environment Variables.
Under System variables, click New to add a new variable.

Set Variable name to JAVA_HOME and Variable value to the path of your JDK installation (e.g., C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23).
Click OK to save the changes.
Add the JDK's bin directory to your system's Path variable:

In the same Environment Variables window, find the Path variable
under System variables and click Edit.
Click New and add the path to the JDK's bin directory (e.g.,
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23\bin).
Close and reopen your command prompt to apply the changes, then
Run flutter doctor --android-licenses Again: Try running the command again to see if the issue is resolved.


I do all of these check up points but the error still shown

check with android sdk,

in android studio check command sdk tools has been dowloaded or not
